# System.FormatException in CCnet

Tags: build, cruisecontrol.net, formatexception

When I try to Build my project via Cruise Control, I get the fallowing error :

```
BUILD EXCEPTION
Error Message:  System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number,               NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseUInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
at System.Convert.ToUInt64(String value)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
Project:    TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G
Date of build:  2012-06-07 13:53:26
Running time:   00:00:03
Integration Request:    Build (ForceBuild) triggered from COREBUILDER
```

I change the version of TortoiseSvn from 1.6 to 1.7 and update the svn command line from 1.6 to 1.7. How can I make my projects build again?

Thanks!

P.S. I went here : http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-634
and here : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.dotnet.ccnet.user/6126
But it did not solve my problem.

- EDIT -

In the CCnet.log I found this (after updating all my files to svn 1.7) :

```
2012-06-07 15:16:45,579 [72:INFO] Project: 'TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G' is added to queue: 'TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G' in position 0. Requestsource : COREBUILDER ()
2012-06-07 15:16:45,594 [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G:INFO] Queue: 'TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G' is attempting to be in-use, trying to lock related queues
2012-06-07 15:16:45,594 [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G:INFO] Project: 'TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G' is first in queue: 'TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G' and shall start integration.
2012-06-07 15:16:45,594 [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G:DEBUG] Checking if C:\REP\TRUNKS_5.2.0\TRPMonitor\trunks_5.01.1 is a svn working folder
2012-06-07 15:16:45,594 [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G:DEBUG] Starting process [C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] in working directory [C:\REP\TRUNKS_5.2.0\TRPMonitor\trunks_5.01.1] with arguments [info http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/svn/svn-payments-core/ --username XXXXXXXX --password ******** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --xml]
594 [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G:DEBUG] Not setting PriorityClass on [C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] to default Normal
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <info>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <entry
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe]    path="svn-payments-core"
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe]    revision="75905"
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe]    kind="dir">
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <url>http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/svn/svn-payments-core</url>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <repository>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <root>http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/svn/svn-payments-core</root>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <uuid>12d69269-45e3-204f-b74b-a9c2047a3d92</uuid>
2012-06-07 15:16:45,844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] </repository>
2012-06-07 15:16:45,844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <commit
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe]    revision="75905">
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <author>XXXXXX</author>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] <date>2012-06-07T19:15:34.949697Z</date>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] </commit>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] </entry>
844 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] </info>
954 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] standard-error stream closed -- null received in event
954 [4:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] standard-output stream closed -- null received in event
969 [72:DEBUG] [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G C:\Program Files\svn-win32-1.7.5\svn.exe] process exited event received
985 [TRPMonitor 5.2.0 10G 11G:WARN] Source control failure (GetModifications): Input string was not in a correct format.
```

It seems that the error comes from the SVN command line ...

Comment: So the build was working before you switched to 1.7?  Have you tried deleting the source code on the build server so it re-grabs everything?  If that doesn't work, you might want to post the svn section of your build file so we have an idea as to what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng) for svn 1.7, it looks like there were changes to how the metadata is stored (instead of multiple .svn folders, there is now only one.)  Try deleting all of the source code on the build box and let ccnet re-pull everything.

Comment: I was testing this when I read your answer ... If it works, I'll accept it.

Comment: Have you tried manually pulling down code with the command-line version of svn?  Maybe the install didn't work correctly?

Comment: I got it working by installing the new version of CruiseControl.net. I will put your answer as accepted since you helped me. Thanks.